# Clear input line after newline

Tags: c, stdio

I'm writing a C program that accepts input one line at a time from the user. However, after the user enters the line of input, I want to either clear the line they typed from stdout, or prefix it. The former is ideal, but the latter would be acceptable for my purposes. Is there a way to do this? Tell me if I need to be more clear, I'm not sure how well I've described the problem.

Comment: You cannot "clear a line from stdout". C has no notion of a terminal or of printing data. It only knows an opaque input and output `FILE*` that produces/eats bytes. Anything else is platform-specific and typically involved terminal handling.

Comment: Yeah, I figured any way to do it would be messy if not impossible.

Comment: People like to be able to type ahead; why would you want to stop them from doing so?

Comment: Basically my program takes the user input and reformats it, I would clear whatever the user inputs and just show the formatted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot in C portably clear a line after a new line was issued.

On most POSIX systems you can use ncurses library to position the cursor and clear any line.

Comment: That looks like what I want. Thanks.